# PayPal SDK Sandbox mode returns response with the wrong links

Tags: .net, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm using PayPal .NET SDK for REST API v1.5 and I've always been able to successfully use the sandbox mode for testing. Since this afternoon *create payment API* (creating them with authorize intent) in sandbox mode gives me a response with the wrong links, more specifically:

```
1. GET, SELF, https://127.0.0.1/v1/payments/payment/PAY-3J041487P5058351GKYHKEDQ
2. REDIRECT, AUTHORIZE, https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-2W7266730F1412848
3. POST, EXECUTE, https://127.0.0.1/v1/payments/payment/PAY-3J041487P5058351GKYHKEDQ/execute
```

I've always got back the sandbox links for the 3 of them whilst now, as you can see, 2 of them point to localhost and one (the one that I actually need to authorize the payment) points to Live paypal.

When using Live mode instead of sandbox everything works fine.

Anyone else getting this ? Could it be just a temporary problem with the sandbox environment? or could it depend on the SDK?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a problem with the sandbox environment. PayPal is aware of the issue and is working to resolve it. I will follow up here, when I have more information.

Edit: The issue should now be resolved as of Oct 5 at 11:35 AM PDT

Comment: The approval_url has been corrected, we are further following up on the self and execute URLs.